# AWS Postgres setting pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold

Tags: amazon-rds

Trying to set pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold on an RDS postgres instance (postgres 12 if it matters):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold = 0.3;
```

I get the error:
`must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command`

I don't see this in the parameter groups even though pg_trgm is a supported extension. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'll remove the "postgres" tag, because that question has nothing to do with PostgreSQL, only with the modifications and additions by Amazon.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, have you ever solved this issue, then?
I'm facing the same problem and I need to increase that 0.3 default value to and higher value (0.5 or even 0.7) to improve similarity matches through % operator in my scenario, but I get your same error...

Comment: I think you have to change this value though the editing of RDS Parameter group set, by adding a new key `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` with the value you want.
BTW, 0.3 should be the default.

Comment: ... but [it looks like](https://repost.aws/questions/QUhf2ksaV2SA-MWaw04M4U_Q/changing-pg-trgm-similarity-threshold-in-rds) it is not yet possible to add that parameter to the set 

Comment: Then the solution could be *not* to use Amazon.